# How to clear cookies from single site in Google Chrome version 62

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

The instructions given for clearing individual cookies at the Google help page at https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en is incorrect for version 62, it seems.

Under Advanced settings, Privacy and Security, Clear Browsing Data one can only clear ALL cookies back for a period of time specified in the drop down menu.  I can't seem to find any way of clearing ALL cookies from a specific site the way it was possible in the past (and the way specified in the help page).

Has this been moved to another place in the Settings interface, or has Google deleted the ability to manage cookies site by site?

Comment: This is not right SE site for this kind of question, I'd suggest you ask this on SuperUser.

Answer (score 7):

The fastest way (at least in Chrome 63) is just to open the following url:

```
chrome://settings/siteData
```

Just pick the site you're interested in and you'll see all cookies (or other artifacts like cache, localstorage, etc.).

Comment: This is now located at chrome://settings/content/all?search=site+data

Answer (score 4):

This is now buried deep in Chrome > Preferences > Advanced > Privacy & Security > Content Settings > Cookies > See all cookies and site data!

Fortunately you can get straight there by typing - chrome://settings/siteData in the address bar.

Once it loads, you can search for & delete individual cookies

Comment: That used to be true, but from Chrome 75 on MacOs (and a few versions before I believe), you no longer see "Content Settings" in the privacy and security settings.

Answer (score 0):

Click the "i" next to the domain. There should be the word "Cookies" and under that the text " used". Click that. Now select the first one and spam-click "Remove" until the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I Found one more powerful way to delete the site's client-side data. Go to Developer tools(F12) under the application tab, select clear storage.
can clear

- Cookies
- Cache
- Indexed DB
- Web SQL
- Service Workers

and a lot more.

[image]